# Ordering by taxonomy field ascending but leaving those node without taxonomy at the bottom

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a View of products (nodes). They have taxonomy associated, and I am displaying the taxonomy first and ordering by taxonomy ascending. However, I would like to have all with taxonomy ordered first, but I find that the View shows first those without taxonomy, and later those with taxonomy, in this case in the correct order. How could I indicate the View that it must reserve those without taxonomy for the last, i. e.

```
 A Taxonomy
   - Product 1
   - Product 2
 B Taxonomy
   - Product 3
   - Product 4
 ...
 Z Taxonomy
  - Product 5

  -- Products with No taxonomy -- (this message does not display, it is only for clarification here)
  - Product 6
  - Product 7
```

...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to modify your main view to list only Product nodes with a taxonomy term selected, then use an attachment to your main view that lists Product nodes with no taxonomy term. The attachment would be displayed after your main view.

## Steps

**1. Filter your main view to list only Product nodes with a taxonomy term value**

In your main view's configuration, under Filter Criteria, add a filter for your taxonomy term field (choose either dropdown or autocomplete), and select **"Is not empty (NOT NULL)"**.

[image: Filter by not empty]

**2. Create the attachment that lists Product nodes with no taxonomy term value**

Add an **Attachment** display to your view.

[image: Add attachment display]

Under **Attachment settings**, set **Attach to** to your main view display (in this example the main view is Page), and set the **Attachment position** to After.

[image: Attachment settings]

In the attachment display's **Filter Criteria**, change the taxonomy term filter to **"Is empty (NULL)"**. Make sure to override this setting for the attachment display only or it will apply to the main view as well.

[image: Filter by empty]

## Note about the attachment header

Your attachment view will be displayed right after your main view, so you may want to add a Header to the attachment (make sure to override to the attachment display only).

[image: Text area header]

In this example I used a Text area.

[image: Header settings for the attachment]

Alternatively, you could add a label to the taxonomy term field. **Make sure to override this setting for the attachment display only** or it will apply back to the main view.

[image: Label settings]

## Results

Your main view should now list your Product nodes by taxonomy term in ascending order, and your Product nodes with no value selected for the taxonomy at the bottom of the list.

[image: Results]

Comment: Thank  you very much, this is way more elegant that the two ideas I had in mind: modifying the SQL query adding the NULL condition or creating a new vocabulary which would be opposite of the main taxonomy vocabulary, to group those without taxonomy and order by those two fields. Elegant solution, yours.

Comment: You're quite welcome! Modifying the SQL was a thought I had as well. Thank you for the kind words!